# Form display showing in box

Tags: javascript, html

MY HTML and JS.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type= "text/javascript">
    function gender()
    {
        var mygender=document.getElementById("mygender");
        document.getElementById("maleorfemale").value=mygender.options[mygender.selectedIndex].text;

    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form>
    Gender: 
    <select id= "mygender" onChange="gender()">
        <option></option>
         <option>Male</option>
        <option>Female</option> 
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="maleorfemale"> 
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

what should i do to display the chosen type (M or F) in a test without the box. For example i pick Male, i want the result male to comeout but not in side the box, i want it to be Male with out the box

Comment: So assign an id to a div element, what you are waiting for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
<input type="text" id="maleorfemale">
```

to

```
<div id="maleorfemale"/>
```

and

```
document.getElementById("maleorfemale").value=mygender.options[mygender.selectedIndex].text;
```

to

```
document.getElementById("maleorfemale").innerHTML=mygender.options[mygender.selectedIndex].text;
```